# Glympse API Crash when trying to create/send a new Ticket

Tags: glympse

I am trying to incorporate the Glympse Lite iOS SDK  v1.0.2 into my app but have run into a problem.  I have added the framework and resource bundle, and have been following along with the examples.  However when I try to run this line:

```
bool succeeded = [GlympseLiteWrapper instance].glympse->sendTicket(_glympseTicket, wizardFlags);
```

I get this exception:

```
+[NSBundle liteBundle]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10f5620
```

Which appears to be coming from the framework:  `[GLYConfiguratorViewerOwner ensureWindowCreated]` method.

Any ideas what might be causing this crash?  (The view that this is being called from is within a `UITabBarController` if that makes any difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of error is typically caused by a static framework creating a category on an existing class but the linker failing to include it in the binary.

In build settings, look for **Other Linker Flags**.  First add `-ObjC` or set the value to `$(inherited) -ObjC` if blank.  If that doesn't work, try `$(inherited) -ObjC -all_load`.  These values cause the linker to load every object file.

Comment: adding the flag '$(inherited) -ObjC' did the trick, thanks for the fast and excellent  help!