# Glympse Lite API Dismiss Button crash

Tags: ios, glympse

I am trying to incorporate the Glympse Lite iOS SDK v1.0.12 into my app.
But I have a problem.
Trying to Dismiss "Sending.." screen causes the application to crash.

Tried to use solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17889940/3805275 but still get the crash.

Try to do the same with the sample project GlympseHistoryLiteDemo and also get crash with the following output:

```
 -[GLYConfiguratorViewerOwner onDismissPleaseWait:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15daa5c0
  TICKET_CHANGED FIRED
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'-[GLYConfiguratorViewerOwner onDismissPleaseWait:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15daa5c0'
  *** First throw call stack:
  (0x2e1d0f4b ...) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any ideas what might be causing this crash and possible solution ?

Btw, I was testing on iPod Touch with iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: It seems that this issue is fixed in the new Glympse Lite iOS SDK v1.0.13